# Woocommerce product cropped images issue 3.3 X

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

WooCommerce show cropped images for product everywhere. I am using 3.3X version of woocomerce.This version does not have any image settings.

My theme have these cropping sizes:-

```
$shop_single_image_size_default    = array(555, 710);

# Other Image Sizes
add_image_size('shop-thumb-2', 70, 90, true);
add_image_size('shop-category-thumb', 320, 256, true);
```

These functions display image in specified sizes but they also crop images instead of resizing it.

Please help me how can i show actual image size without cropping.

Comment: Image settings are there you can find it from theme customizer settings area

Comment: Please check this document https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2017/12/11/wc-3-3-image-size-improvements/

Comment: @developerme I already change settings from there but still not effecting product image.I just want to show actual image without resizing or cropping.

Comment: please send me site link or contact me